# How to avoid inclusion of jni c source code file in apk

Tags: android, java-native-interface, apk

I don't know if it's a bug or if there is an option somewhere, but all my c source code files from the jni folder are included in my apk file. Not a good idea. More precisely, it seems that those files copied to bin/classes and then the apk zips them all. If I remove the files from bin/classes, they are not copied back without a jni rebuild. Any idea?

Comment: What tool are you using for building? ANT? Eclipse? AOSP make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Eclipse, aren't you? And you probably have `jni` listed in *Java paths* as source folder. Remove it from there, and your C files will not be copied to bin/classes anymore.